# Select fields on Microsoft Graph list of Messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph to get a list of messages for a user.

I'm using the following URL
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages`

One important thing that is returned by this is the `meetingMessageType` when the message revolves around a meeting request.

I would also like to get the `uniqueBody` of the message.  However, that's not provided by default.  One needs to specifically ask for that field.  I can do that by adding `?$select=uniqueBody` to the URL.

However, that now means that I need to add the rest of the fields I want to the `$select` query parameter.  That's not a big deal until I run into `meetingMessageType`.  Microsoft Graph returns:

> Could not find a property named 'meetingMessageType' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'.

What can I do to ensure I get both `uniqueBody` **and** `meetingMessageType`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$select=uniqueBody, microsoft.graph.eventMessage/meetingMessageType`

Answer (score 0):

Yogesh's answer is close but will result in a `Only one level select is supported` error.

As long as you don't care about the value of `meetingMessageType`, you can use this select:

`$select=microsoft.graph.eventMessage, uniqueBody`

You'll note that the results no longer include `meetingMessageType` as a property. The list however is limited to only those messages that are `eventMessage`, effectively giving you a result set filtered to only show meeting requests.

Comment: The answer @yogesh provides does give me the `Only on level select is supported` error.  This solution still gives me objects `eventMessage` types as well as `message`.  That's what I want.  However as you've pointed out, I don't get `meetingMessageType`.  Is there no way to do what Yogesh suggests without getting an error?

Comment: If you want to get that value, you'll need to make a second request to grab the contents of the eventMessage using the `events` endpoint. This really just provides you a filtered list so you can find the id's you need to fetch.

Comment: Bummers, I was hoping not to make two requests.  Also, it doesn't appear to filter the list at all.  Thanks for the help.